# Asynchronous triggers of multithreaded function to create image from CGPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, cgpath

A combined question here.

How does one spawn a thread to execute a function for drawing Core graphics code? Is it safe? I have an asynchronous callback that will be called in my code when a function completes and I would then like to spawn a new thread to execute a function.

This function will be creating a CGPath and storing its context into a UIImage. Does the actual path need to be rendered to a view or can the draw statements be left out and the context put into a UIImage?

I will be saving the resulting image, as NSData in a plist, to a folder in the documents directory, can files be written to the directory from various threads(still different files)?